# How does one compute a variational derivative?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, calculus

The expected regression loss is given as:$$E[L]=\int\int \{y(\mathbf x)-t\}^2 p(\mathbf x,t)d\mathbf xdt$$
To minimise the expected loss,Euler Lagrange equation is used which goes like this in the general form:$$ \frac{\delta F}{\delta y}=\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{\delta F}{\delta y'}\right)$$ where $F$ is the functional i.e function of function $\mathit y(x)$.
In our case $F$ would correspond to $E$ and $\mathit y$ to $L$.
Please show a step wise application of this equation to yield the following expression
$$\frac{\delta E[L]}{\delta \mathit y(\mathbf x)}=2 \int\{\mathit y(\mathbf x)-t\}p(\mathbf x,t) 
dt=0.$$
Also, please suggest a good reference for all the calculus used in Machine Learning.

Comment: where is $y'$? you don't have it the functional

Answer (score 3):

I will carry out the steps in a way I hope is clear enough to indicate what assumptions must be made about $y,$ $p,$ and $\delta$ to justify the steps.

When a function $y$ is a local minimum of a functional $\mathcal L,$ adding a sufficiently small multiple $h$ of a "test function" $\delta$ cannot decrease the value of the functional.  (Usually a test function is assumed to be arbitrarily smooth and of compact support; in more complex situations it may have to satisfy constraints imposed by boundary conditions.)  That is, writing

$$\mathcal{L}[y] = \iint \left(y(x)-t\right)^2\,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t,$$

it must be the case that for all $|h|$ in some small neighborhood $U$ of $0$ (which may depend on $\delta$),

$$\eqalign{
0 &\le \mathcal{L}[y+h\delta] - \mathcal{L}[y] \\
&= 2h\iint \delta(x) \left(y(x)-t\right)\,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t + h^2 \iint \delta^2(x) \,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t
.}\tag{1}$$

Given $\delta,$ the right hand side is a quadratic function of $h$ with a zero at $h=0.$ (This assertion follows from the fact that the integral of $\delta^2$ is finite, which guarantees both integrals in $(1)$ exist and are finite provided $y$ and $p$ are not too "badly behaved," which is implicitly assumed in the question.)

In order to be non-negative throughout $U$, this zero must be the vertex of the quadratic; that is,

$$0 = 2\iint \delta(x) \left(y(x)-t\right)\,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t$$

This says the function

$$x \to \int \left(y(x)-t\right)p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

is orthogonal to all test functions $\delta,$ implying (by virtue of some assumed "not bad behavior" of $p$) it is almost everywhere zero, *QED.*

---

Generally, to find the derivative of a functional $\mathcal L,$ you proceed as in ordinary differential Calculus to form the difference quotient as in $(1)$

$$\frac{\mathcal{L}[y+h\delta] - \mathcal{L}[y]}{h} = \iint \delta(x)\, 2\left(y(x)-t\right)\,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t + o(h).$$

The right hand side applies the *linear operator*

$$D[\delta] = \int \delta(x)\,\left[2\int (y(x)-t)\,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right]\,\mathrm{d}x$$

represented by the generalized function

$$x \to 2\int (y(x)-t)\,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

to $\delta$ and adds an error term $o(h)$ that is vanishingly small compared to $h.$  This conforms with the (usual) *definition* of the derivative, allowing us to write

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = 2\int (y(x)-t)\,p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Comment: where did the $\int d\mathbf x$ go?

Comment: @Aksakal It was integrated out, due to the $\delta(x)$

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward application of [Euler Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) would lead to the sought result.

First, the derivative of the integrated expression with respect to $y'$ is zero, simply because $y'$ is nowhere to be seen. Here  $F(y(\mathbf x),\mathbf x)=\int (y(\mathbf x)-t)^2 p(\mathbf x,t)dt$, so we get: $\frac{\partial}{\partial y'}F=0$

Second, the derivative of $F$ with respect to $y(\mathbf x)$ is trivial, no need to even apply [Leibnitz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):
$$F_y=  \frac{\partial}{\partial y(\mathbf x)}\int (y(\mathbf x)-t)^2 p(\mathbf x,t)dt
=2\int (y(\mathbf x)-t) p(\mathbf x,t)dt$$

So, there you get the equation that you're looking for:
$$F_y=2\int (y(\mathbf x)-t) p(\mathbf x,t)dt=0$$
This condition minimizes the expectation.

As to reference to *all* math that's used in machine learning, there's no such a thing. Whatever the researches decides to use is a fair game. For instance, [number theory and abstract algebra concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) can be used, like in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.04604.pdf). The most common tools tend to be linear algebra, real analysis (calculus), probability and typical computer science toolset such as graph theory.